# how to fetch the row without repeat

Tags: python, python-2.7, xbmc

I'm working on my python script to pull the data from the sqlite3 database.

I have the list of channels in the database, but I have a problem with print the channels because I have stored 30 channels in sqlite3 database and I want to print one channel at a time without repeat it.

Used this code:

```
#Pull the data from the database
channelList = list()
programList = list()
database_path = 
xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 
'source.db'))

if os.path.exists(database_path):
   #get the channels list
   cur.execute('SELECT channel FROM programs WHERE channel')
   row = cur.fetchone()

   for row in cur:
       channel = row[0].encode('ascii')
       #channelList.append(channel)
       print channel
```

**Result:**

```
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
```

I want to make the result like this:

```
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 101 ABC FAMILY
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:23:14 T:3280  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
```

**EDIT: There are one channel which is missing:**

```
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 102 CBS
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 103 CNN USA
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 105 ESPN USA
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 106 Fox News
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 107 Animal Planet
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 108 USA Network
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 110 SPIKE
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 111 BRAVO USA
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 112 BRAVO1
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 113 BRAVO2
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 114 BRAVO3
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 115 BRAVO4
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 116 BRAVO5
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 117 BRAVO6
16:47:21 T:2196  NOTICE: 118 BRAVO7
```

When I use this code:

```
   if os.path.exists(database_path):
       #get the channels list
       cur.execute('SELECT channel FROM programs WHERE channel GROUP BY channel')
       row = cur.fetchone()

       for row in cur:
           channel = row[0].encode('ascii')
           #channelList.append(channel)
           print channel
```

Comment: Maybe throw a DISTINCT in the SQL statement.  like `SELECT DISTINCT channel FROM programs WHERE channel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing your SQL query in one of two ways:

```
SELECT DISTINCT channel FROM programs WHERE channel
```

Or:

```
SELECT channel FROM programs WHERE channel GROUP BY channel
```

My preference lies with the former, personally, since `GROUP BY` contains a lot of other functionality that's useful for organizing data. I wouldn't rely on it solely for removing duplicates, but the option is there.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, i can see that i can print one channel at a time without repeat, but there are one channel is missing which is called `abc family`. do you know why it have been missing? please see my update post.

Comment: @user3853587 I see you're using the `GROUP BY`, what happens if you use `DISTINCT`?

Comment: I get the same result. However I have removed the code `row = cur.fetchone()` and now it is working. I can print the full list of channels, so thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated!